# Finish the illustration's caption

Tags: wordplay, visual, rebus

Shown below is an excellent illustration from the obscure textbook *"Aquatic Waterfowl and the Physical Properties that Govern Them,"* written by Quincy Adams Wagstaff.

While the acclaimed professor of Freedonia State University was extremely learned in the study of wildlife, his skills regarding the English language left much to be desired.

[image: ![Illustration to decrypt](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/vnob088xvmdt5zu/Rebus.png?dl=0)]

Can you decipher the illustration and determine what **four words** are needed to complete the following caption?

___________ of ___________ go over ___________ before ___________ .

Answer (score 20, accepted):

My answer is

> **Defeat** of **deduct** go over **defence** before **detail**

which corresponds to the picture in that

> **The feet** of **the duck** go over  **the fence** before **the tail**

I think it refers to

> A popular joke where an English student or non-native speaker is asked to put all of the words "defeat", "deduct", "defence" and "detail" into a single sentence.